# Finding $ \mathbb{P} (|x-y| \geq \rho )$ where $x$ and $y$ are uniform on $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $x$ and $y$ be two independent  random variables distributed according to uniform law over $[-1,1]$.

I would like to compute the following probability, for a parameter $\rho \in (0,1)$:

$$ \mathbb{P} (|x-y| \geq \rho )$$

For $|x-y|= x - y$ (then the other case $|x-y|= -x + y$), I set $Z=x + (-y)$, so that I compute :
\begin{align} 
\mathbb{P} ( Z \geq \rho ) & = 1 - \mathbb{P} ( Z < \rho ) & \\
& = 1 - \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{\rho + y } f (y) f(x) \,dy \,dx & \text{ where } f \text{ is the PDF of the unifrom law over } [-1,1]\\
& = 1 - \int_{-1}^{1} F(\rho +y )   f(y) \,dy  & \\
& = 1 - \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\rho + y -  (-1)}{1 -(-1)} \frac{1}{2} dy & \\
& = 1 - \frac{1}{4} \big( [(\rho+1 ) y]^{1}_{-1} + [\frac{y^2}{2}]^{1}_{-1} \big) & \\
& = 1 - \frac{1}{2} ( \rho + 1)  
 \end{align}

Is this correct ? ($x-y$ take values between $-2$ and $2$)

Answer (score 1):

You need to worry about the case where $\rho+y\gt1$, in which case you only integrate $\int_{-1}^1 dx$.
It might help to draw the region in the $(x,y)$ plane.

Comment: thank you very much, it helped a lot to draw the region in the (x,y) plane